# dnsmasq: Custom name resolution for different clients

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have a network on which I'm running dnsmasq to do DHCP and DNS.  My network has several clients each of which needs to communicate with a master machine (which they do with a DNS query to dnsmasq for `master`). I now want to run several master/client groups on the same network, and I want to be able to easily configure which client is associated with which master.

Is it possible to configure dnsmasq such that it will give a different response for a certain DNS query to different clients?  For example, if `10.0.2.23` queries for `master` I want the result to be `10.0.3.1`. However, if `10.0.2.24` queries for `master` I want the result to be `10.0.3.2`.

I know I can achieve this by just making a `master` entry in each client's `/etc/hosts` file, but I would love if this information was all in one single config file (e.g. `/etc/dnsmasq.d/masterclient.conf`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: explicit is better than implicit**

You may also want to ensure that any diagnostics you run on your network also reveal the connection between members of each pair.

If dnsmasq is doing both dns & dhcp, its easy to solve both your "each client knows their master" problem and to make verifying the correct setup possible - by NOT making dnsmasq respond differently based on who is querying.

I recommend you instead make sure each client ask for its master specifically by making its group a part of its fully qualified domain name:

```
# make sure your dhcp clients use dnsmasq as dns & split them in groups
#  (you probably already do that baes on either mac or subnet)
dhcp-range=set:group1,10.0.2.0,10.0.2.23,255.255.255.0,4h
dhcp-range=set:group2,10.0.2.24,10.0.2.50,255.255.255.0,4h
dhcp-otion=option:dns-server,0.0.0.0

# based on tags, give them a dns search domain
dhcp-option=tag:group1,option:domain-search,pair1.local
dhcp-option=tag:group2,option:domain-search,pair2.local

# making the respective master address known to them
address=/master.pair1.local/10.0.3.1
address=/master.pair2.local/10.0.3.2
```

There are ways to base the decision about which client is in which group on different parameters; depending on what determines which group a client should be my example splitting in `dhcp-range` may be either sufficient or completely inappropriate.

Caveat: Reconfiguring clients into different groups can only be done in accordance with DHCP lease times - which is less flexible than dns TTL.